# How to make VM in VirtualBox start headless by default?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, headless

How to make VM in VirtualBox start headless by default? Not to press SHIFT every time to start headless...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

execute command

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "vmname" --defaultfrontend headless
```

refer: [GUI Always Start Headless](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13308)

Comment: Why have a manual when there is Stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Commenting on a relic but I think it's worth mentioning that you can set the default for *all* VMs to start headless by setting the global configuration via:

```
VBoxManage setproperty defaultfrontend headless
```

Comment: thanks for that. Note that it is VBoxManage with a capital B, but I can't edit the answer because it's only 1 character difference.